# Dependent dropdown in a for loop

Tags: php, sql

I have 3 dropdown in a `for` loop written in php code.

```
<?php
    for ($u=1;$u<=$slot;++$u){
        $y=$u-1;
        ++$uu;
        echo "PR: <SELECT  name='prog[$uu]' id='prog{$uu}'><option></option>";
        $az1=mysql_query("select distinct Programme from details");
        while ($az2=mysql_fetch_array($az1)){
            echo "<option >$az2[Programme]</option>";
        }
        echo "</select>";
        echo "CR: <SELECT name='course[$uu]' id='course{$uu}' ><option></option>";
        $az1=mysql_query("select distinct Course from details order by Course");
        while ($az2=mysql_fetch_array($az1))
        {
            echo "<option >$az2[Course]</option>";
        }
        echo "</select>&emsp;";
        echo "CO: <SELECT name='counsellor[$uu]' id='counsellor{$uu}' ><option></option>";
        $az1a=mysql_query("select  distinct Counsellor from counsellor");
        while ($az2a=mysql_fetch_array($az1a)){ 
            echo "<option >$az2a[Counsellor]</option>";
        }
        echo "</select>";
    }
?>
```

I want to make them dependent so that the `CR` depends on `PR` and `CO` depends on `CR`.

Please help me.

[image]

I am confused for the `for` loop. In the absence of `for` loop, I have used

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function(){
 var $cat6 = $("#cat6"),
 $subcat6 = $("#subcat6");  
 $cat6.on("change",function(){
     var _rel = $(this).val();
     $subcat6.find("option").attr("style","");
      $subcat6.val("");
      if(!_rel) return $subcat6.prop("disabled",true);
      $subcat6.find("[rel="+_rel+"]").show();
       $subcat6.prop("disabled",false);
 });
});


  $(function(){
  var $cat6 = $("#cat6"),
  $subcat7 = $("#subcat7");  

  $cat6.on("change",function(){
      var _rel = $(this).val();
      $subcat7.find("option").attr("style","");
      $subcat7.val("");
      if(!_rel) return $subcat7.prop("disabled",true);
      $subcat7.find("[rel="+_rel+"]").show();
      $subcat7.prop("disabled",false);
 });
});
 </script>  

 </head>
 </html>
 <?php
  echo "<form action='sc4b.php' method='post' target='_blank'>";


  echo "PROGRAMME: <SELECT  name='prog'  id='cat6' required><option>
            </option>
           <OPTGROUP LABEL='Bachelor Degree Programme'>
          <option>BDP</option><option>BSW</option><option>BCA</option>
          <option>BTS</option>
        </OPTGROUP>
   <OPTGROUP LABEL='Master Degree Programme'>
   <option>MEG</option><option>MPS</option><option>MAEDU</option>
     <option>M.Com</option>
    <option>MAPY</option><option>MAH</option><option>MSW</option>
    <option>MEC</option>
    <option>MARD</option><option>MSO</option>
    </OPTGROUP></select>";

   echo "COURSE: <SELECT name='course' id='subcat6'   required><option>
   </option>";
   $az1=mysql_query("select * from details");
    while ($az2=mysql_fetch_array($az1))
       {
         echo "<option rel='$az2[Programme]'>$az2[Course]</option>";

       }
   echo "</select>";

   echo "COUNSELLOR: <SELECT name='counsellor' id='subcat7'   required>
   <option></option> ";
   $az1a=mysql_query("select * from counsellor");
   while ($az2a=mysql_fetch_array($az1a))
    {
    echo "<option rel='$az2a[Programme]'>$az2a[Counsellor]</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>";
```

I want to know how to modify this code so that the `for` loop issue can be addressed. Without `for` loop name and id is the following form

```
name='name'  id='id'
```

but within for loop it is

```
name='name[$i]'  id='id{$i}'
```

I am confused how to include the `$i` in the jquery script.

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask]. Also, re-format your code as to make it readable, please.

Comment: Similar reference example. https://www.codexworld.com/dynamic-dependent-select-box-using-jquery-ajax-php/

Comment: @Nitin is right, you have to pass an `id` in the `<option>` which is a foreign key in the second table in the database so as to connect the two drop downs.

Comment: just use JS to validate dynamically (jQuery validate is a good library to use) OR  use PHP if you want to validate on form submit.